# Invalid Uri: The Uri scheme is not valid

Tags: c#, uri

I am trying to make a connection via HttpWebRequest. I am reading url links from a text file. 
However, I am getting 'System.UriFormatException' error.

I have tried to add http:// in front of the url links in my text file. But the result is the same.

What can be the solution?

Comment: Can you give us a sample url?

Comment: sure, the thing is if I copy the url from my text file into a String variable and than try to make webrequest connnection it works. for example: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/43524

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the error only occurs when reading the values from a file, but not when assigned directly to a `string` variable, then I'm guessing that there are extra characters being read (quotes, escaped characters, carriage-return/line feeds, etc).

Try reading the first value into a `string`, and then comparing that to what you expect in the explicit `string` value. Any differences should be obvious after that.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel. You are right, I assigned streamreader readline to a string with trim() and it worked.

Comment: @Val No problem. Don't forget to flag which posts answered your questions (for other readers). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code it's impossible to tell what you're trying to do. But you can start by looking at the **[Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx)** property of the UriFormatException class. `Message` is a string that explains the reason for the exception.

Comment: this is the line of code I get error:
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
url is a String read from a text file. Text file contains url links in each line.
an example URL is:
http://appworld.blackberry.com//webstore/content/22443

Comment: Make sure you're removing the trailing newline from `url` after reading it from the file. Look at the `Message` property of the UriFormatException class to get more information about the exception- otherwise we're just guessing at what could be wrong.